# No sound through HDMI on my NUC

Tags: sound, hdmi, tv

I have a new Kaby lake NUC. HDMI is listed as an option in 'Sound Settings' and if I open pavucontrol I can see the 'sound monitor bar' flickering up and down when I play a youtube video, but no sound comes out of my TV.

If I plug headphones into the front-socket then the port for HDMI 2 'HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (plugged in)' disappears and is replaced by the the headphones, but HDMI isn't available in the drop-down. I thought that was strange.

The only thing I can think this might be is because this is an older TV and could be using HDMI 1, not HDMI 2.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC255 Analog [ALC255 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I also went through speaker-test and manually tried each device but can't get a test tone through any of the devices.

e.g.

```
speaker-test -D hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=1 -c 2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: cat /proc/asound/car*/co* |  grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC255
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI

Comment: The manual hints that the TV uses HDMI 1.3 at least, since it requests a cable of that spec or higher

Comment: I've got the same problem. did you find some fix to this?

Comment: There's a firmware update on the Asus website that supposedly fixes it. It didn't work. I'm using a display port-> HDMI cable instead.

Comment: This is a Thinkpad E470. Just checked in Lenovo's site that there are a bunch of bios updates for this model, so I'll give it a try. Thanks!